# Simulation of LM13700 in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to simulate a sample LM13700 circuit but it's not working for some reason. I need some help identifying why it isn't working.

[image]

This is contents of the lm13700.sub file:

```
.OPTIONS GMIN      =1e-18  METHOD     =TRAP   set srcsteps = 1
VCC     VCC    0      DC    10
VIN     INP    INN    SIN( 0 100m 1k )   AC 1m
IBias   VCC    IAB    1m
R1      VCC    INN    1k
R2      INN    0      1k
R3      VCC    OUT    1k
R4      OUT    0      1k
XOTA    LIN    INP    INN  IAB  OUT   VCC   BIN  BUF  HALF13700
R5      BIN    OUT    1
R6      BUF    0      1000k

.control
set          pensize = 2
tran         1u       10m
run
plot         v(inp)   v(inn)  v(out)
ac           dec      200     1      10000k
plot         db(v(out))
.endc



.SUBCKT HALF13700    LIN   INP   INN  IAB  OUT VCC   BIN  BUF

QN1     IAB   VN2B   0     npnv     3
QN2     VN2B  VN2B   0     npnv     3
QN3     VN3C  IAB    VN2B  npnv     3
QN4     VP3B  INN    VN3C  npnv     3
QN5     VP6B  INP    VN3C  npnv     3
QN6     LIN   LIN    INN   npnv     3
QN7     LIN   LIN    INP   npnv     3
QN8     VN10B VN9B   0     npnv     3
QN9     VN9B  VN9B   0     npnv     3
QN10    OUT   VN10B  VN9B  npnv     3
QN11    VCC   BIN    VN12B npnv     15
QN12    VN12B VN12B  BUF   npnv     3
QN13    VCC   VN12B  BUF   npnv     150
QP1     VP3B  VP2B   VCC   pnpl     3
QP2     VP2B  VP2B   VCC   pnpl     3
QP3     VN10B VP3B   VP2B  pnpl     3
QP4     VP6B  VP5B   VCC   pnpl     3
QP5     VP5B  VP5B   VCC   pnpl     3
QP6     OUT   VP6B   VP5B  pnpl     3
.ends

.MODEL  npnv      NPN(
*==========================================================
+IS=1.1E-18     NF=1.005   BF=220        VAF=130      IKF=5e-03
+ISE=9.15E-15   NE=2
*==========================================================
+CJE=2E-12 CJC=2E-13 CJS=3E-12 TF=.6E-9 )

.MODEL  pnpl     PNP(
*==========================================================
+IS=1.1E-18     NF=1.8   BF=5        VAF=170      IKF=6e-03
+ISE=3E-15      NE=3
*==========================================================
+CJE=4E-12 CJC=6E-13 CJS=5E-12 TF=70E-9 )



.end
```

Comment: The text you pasted appears to be a complete ngspice netlist including a `.control` block.  Can you clarify what you pasted between what's in the `lm13700.sub` file and what's shown in your schematic (including the unlabeled Darlington transistor)?

Comment: Thank you for making the edits to my post. What did you do the fix the formatting? As for the information you are asking asking for, I'm not sure what information you want. The text file I posted is the contents of the lm13700.sub file

Comment: @user1505399 What Ste is saying is that the contents of the `lm13700.sub` has lines that are not recognized by LTspice, so if you used that file as it is (e.g. with a simple `.inc`, or `.lib`), errors should have come out -- you need to give us the *exact* errors, otherwise there's not enough information. Also, you have a Darlington transistor which is not part of the default installation of LTspice, but you did not post its `.subckt` or `.model`. Use ``` at the beginning and at the end to enclose multi-line code.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you for the clarification, I will try to see if I can get that information. So far it hasn't actually given me an error, the simulation simply does produce "valid" results. It does not operate as a VCO, but simply a fixed frequency oscillator. A change in control voltage causes no change in output frequency